# How to restrict access folders in All Tags Subversion?

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

I have a directory structure in Subversion.

The problem is that I generate numerous tags, and now need to restrict access within them.

Need to do something generic.

```
[Repo:/tags/**/folder]
developers = 
Administrator = rw
```

The problem is that does not work, developers continue with permission.

There is a way out or do I have to do the configuration for each tag generated?

Answer (score 3):

Subversion doesn't support wildcards for path-based authorization. You need to restrict at a higher level, or specify the paths individually.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I generate numerous tags, and now need to restrict access within them.

Two things:

- **Don't create so many tags**. You can always use revision numbers as *tags*, and in many sites, that's what they do. Someone will say *"Did we have a code review on revision 54220?"*  Using revision numbers as *tags* will save you from creating so many of them. If you use a CI system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), you can use the build numbers as *tags* since these point back to a particular Subversion revision.
- **Why are you trying to restrict access to tags**? Is there suddenly some super secret information that is on that tag that wasn't previously in where that tag came from? You can't use wildcards in the `svnaccess` file.

I take it that the ***real*** issue is that you have too many tags, and users listing them out take a long, long time. Plus, it's hard to find the tag your looking for if you've got 20,000 of them under `/tags`. In that case, simply delete tags you no longer need.

*But, won't that mean we'll lose information? What if I found out I need that tag?*

Subversion doesn't delete anything permanently. You can always get back an old revision if you need it. Let's say you deleted an old tag:

```
 $ svn delete http://repo/svn/tags/2.4
```

Now, you realize you need that particular revision for some odd reason. Maybe there was still a customer on that old revision. How do you get it back after it was delete?

First, you find out in what revision it was deleted in:

```
$ svn log -v http://repo/svn/tags

...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
r32394 | alroc | 2003-01-17 22:56:19 -0600 (Fri, 17 Jan 2003) | 1 line
   Changed Paths:
      D /tags/2.4
Deleted obsolete tag that's no longer needed
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There! It was deleted in revision -r32394. That means in the previous Subversion revision (32393), it still existed. Let's checkout that tag from revision 32393:

```
$ svn checkout -r32393 http://repo/svn/tags/2.4@32393
```

All done. We have that old code back. What if you need that tag back into your repository, copy it back to `/tags`:

```
$ svn copy -r32393 http://repo/svn/tags/2.4@32393 http://repo/svn/tags
```

Now, `/tags/2.4` is back.

---

If you really, really don't like deleting tags, then create a tag archive directory somewhere, and move obsolete tags to that. This way, you're not *deleting* the tag, but then you don't end up seeing it when you do a `svn ls http://repo/svn/tags`.

The problem with this is if you want to do a dump and load (for example, you're separating off a project into another repo), the `svndumpfilter` gets all messed up if you don't include the archived tags.

The best bet is not to create the problem in the first place. Only create tags for releases, and then delete tags if you still feel there are too many of them.